# Facebook Login Button with redirection

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

i recently started working on a project that it required a Facebook login button.
I have successfully set up the button apart from the part where I must redirect the user to my dashboard area which must only be accessible to registered users.

From my understanding I need to fill this field here in the developers facebook settings page

[image]

which will redirect the user to my dashboard. I am guessing that the redirection link must include a token which will login the user automatically in my dashboard. Am I right so far?
My concern is if that link can be accessed by anyone and if someone get their hands on it can use it to login to my app without registering.

Comment: If you are talking about the Login Button plugin - that is for the client-side login flow. The Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field is only relevant for the server-side login flow.

Comment: (And asking for external resources such as tutorials etc., is explicitly considered off topic here.)

Comment: @CBroe edited.. can you explain what you mean is only relevant for the server side login flow?

Comment: There are two different “login flows” - the client-side one, that opens a popup, and where you handle the response client-side, usually in JavaScript; and the server-side login flow, where the user gets redirected to the login dialog, then back to your app, and you need to exchange the passed code for a token via a server-side API call.

Comment: @CBroe yes, i understand that. My remaining question is if I include a static token  in the Valid OAuth link will there be any securities issues etc?

Comment: What token are you talking about now?

Comment: @CBroe how will I login the user into the dashboard? the link in the Valid OAuth should contain a token right?

Comment: Are you talking about the `state` value? That is used for CSRF prevention, and as such, it will only work if it is _not_ static or predictable. And _because_ it changes all the time, it does not need to be included in the URL(s) you specify in that field, this parameter is the only exception in that regard.